# Tmux session created inside jenkins shell script is deleted after job is finished

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, tmux

I'm creating session with tmux to run meteor in background like below:

`tmux new-session -d -s RocketChat 'meteor'`

All is going well but when Jenkins job is finished then I'm getting 'Exited from signal: SIGTERM' and my tmux session disappears 
[image]

Operating system is Ubuntu 14.

Could someone help me with this ? I would like to keep my server running after jenkins job is finished. I'll be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Putting the whole commend between BUILD_ID=dontKillMe and & helped:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe tmux new-session -d -s RocketChat 'meteor' &
```